# Node access based on view mode

Tags: 7, users, entities

I have a content type with multiple fields. Some of the fields are accessible to everyone and there are other fields for which the access is controlled.

Example: There is a content type called Reports with fields like title, summary, body etc. Title and summary should be visible to everyone but the access to body field is controlled.

For implementing this I need to have 2 view modes. one of them will have the fields title and summary displayed with the rest of the fields hidden. The other view mode will have only the body field visible. I am planning to implement the hook hook_node_access to derive the access permissions for the node. So how can I get the view mode in this hook so that I can have my access check based on the view mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some searches but I couldn't find any module that does this. But you can implement the `hook_node_view()` like this:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
    global $user;
    //verify that the user is not loged and the view mode is full view
    if(in_array('anonymous user', $user->roles) && $view_mode == 'full') {
        //denied the access
        drupal_access_denied();
        //avoids other hooks are invoked
        drupal_exit();
    }
}
```

I tested the above code and it works.

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 7 you can use [Field Permissions](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set
>   field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

Comment: In my case the access permissions are not based on user role. The access is specified at the user level and it is controlled using custom code. So I dont think Field Permissions module helps my case.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8+

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_view().
 * @param array $build
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display
 * @param $view_mode
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_node_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
  $displayId = $display->id();
  if ($displayId === 'node.YOUR_NODE_TYPE.default') {
    $roles = \Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles();
    if (!in_array('administrator', $roles, TRUE)) {
      throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
    }
  }
}
```

- Replace `YOUR_MODULE` with your module machine name.
- Replace `YOUR_NODE_TYPE` with the machine name of the content type.
- Add use statements for the entity and display classes.